# Logo screen that appears before SplashScreen is activated in the react-native-splash-screen library

Tags: react-native, react-native-splash-screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boe7y.png)The small logo is supposed to be seen first before the splash screen you set as shown in the video below appears.

You have not found a place to delete this setting. I'm looking for help.

/android/app/src/main/res/layout/launch_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/launch_screen" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There's nothing "before the splash screen", you'll either have to make this the splash screen or make your splash screen play a video.